# Composición con imagen de separación expandir su color de fondo hasta el pie de la vista en SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Estoy intentanto recrear el siguiente diseño en SwiftUI

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El de color rojo, quiero que ese ondulación sea el divisor, tengo en vectorial eso, en un Shpae WaveSeparatorView

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero que se muestre en la parte central y se rellene de color rojo hasta pie de la vista y que el titulo y texto queden por encima de ellos

es decir estructura

- cover
- separador ondulado
- relleno del color

  - titulo
  - descripción
- pie el indicador de puntos